# CI Build failed at Bitbucket Pipelines CI/CD

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I wanted to add build status badge to my project, just to make it more fancy, I did it with Travis CI in my [github repo](https://github.com/ajfmo/Sislic) and works fine (I guess), so I wanted to do the same with a project in Bitbucket using Pipelines integrated addon, but build always fail.

This error is the one preventing my to succeed:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pos: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nubeclick:pos:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javafx:jfxrt:jar:1.8 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar -> [Help 1]
```

This is the .yml config:

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  default:
- step:
    caches:
      - maven
    script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
      - mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
```

I'm really new into this, one thing led me to another, and now I just want to make this work properly.

[Pipeline Log Detail](https://pastebin.com/7uSjtSYH)

I can see that is something about the fxml package, but still haven't figure out the solution.

So what should I do to make the build pass, of what information should I read to do this as should be done.

[Here you can see the Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/nubeclick/posnubeclick/addon/pipelines/home#!/)

Comment: From your pipelines link, it looks like you solved this? If so, can you share your solution here?

Comment: @phod I will do it rigth now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved, all I had to do was make my project public, the API from those tools was not able to inspect properly my project.

Hope it helps to others.